# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Tags: kotlin

```
 fun getNameAlias(str: String): String {

        var nameLetter = ""
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
            nameLetter = str!![0].toString()
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str.split("\\s ")[0])) {
            var index: Int = str.indexOf(" ")
            if (index > 0) {

                nameLetter += if (index == -1) "" else str.substring(index + 1)[0]
            }
        }
        return nameLetter
    }
```

this is  my function to get first charter and last character  when i pass String first character before space and first character  after space but for some character which is blank or  special character i am getting

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

how to fix this issue? i tried  `if (index > 0) { }`  but still same  issue .

Comment: The string is zero length. Empty. Nothing in it. Nada. Niente. Nulla.

Comment: what condition we should apply i have applied string.length greater than zero then also its not working  @EJP

Comment: are you getting SOBE at line nameLetter += if (index == -1) "" else str.substring(index + 1)[0]

Comment: yes ejectly i am getting there only @Afgan

Comment: index + 1 causes problem, because if you string length 2 [0,1] . suppose  your index value is 1 then index + 1 -> would be 2 which which is not present, hence it will throw SOBE

Comment: so how i will handle it can you please tell me Solution @Afgan

Comment: Try to use Index directly instead of index+1 -> str.substring(index)

Comment: but if we will use that one then i am not able to get first charter after Space  like if we  Shaun Marsh then it should print S M

Comment: can you tell me the input for which this is happening?

Comment: (#) or (9989892) or "Basi" like this @swayamraina

Answer (score 0):

For the example string "Basi"
`If (index > 0)` part of the code handles the error. the index variable returns -1 if `" "` is not found.
For the string `"Basi "`, you should update the code
`if (index == -1)` 
to
`if (index == str.length-1)`

For getting an extra space, you can update the `else` part to 
`" " + str.substring(index + 1)[0]` i.e. 
`if (index == str.length-1) "" else " " + str.substring(index + 1)[0]`

Comment: i added same thing u can see  in my code @swayamraina

Comment: the second update I have mentioned. Please try that too.
`if (index == str.length-1)`

Comment: but i am not getting after space first charter i am getting like this like Saun Marsh then its printing SN @swayamraina

Comment: What should be the output for `Saun Marsh`?

Comment: Please check now, @MARSH